# Django: ORM/SQL query speed significantly decreased after adding additional BooleanField or (SQL tinyint) to Django Filter

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

Using MySQL Latest Django:

I have a vaguely complex Django query that works quite quickly--until I add an additional "AND" with a Boolean Field--
See Below:

```
queriedForms = queryFormtype.form_set.filter(is_public=True) 
newQuery = queriedForms.filter(formrecordattributevalue__record_value__icontains=term['TVAL'], formrecordattributevalue__record_attribute_type__pk=rtypePK)
newQuery = newQuery.filter(flagged_for_deletion=False)
logger.info(newQuery.query)
term['count'] =  newQuery.count()
```

If I either remove the initial "is_public=True"  or the final "flagged_for_deletion=False)--it works incredibly fast. If I use both as filters, it increases the time for the count() function by something like 2000%

The different QuerySet.query outputs are below:

```
SELECT `maqluengine_form`.`id`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_name`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_number`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_geojson_string`, `maqluengine_form`.`hierarchy_parent_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`is_public`, `maqluengine_form`.`project_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_created`, `maqluengine_form`.`created_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_last_modified`, `maqluengine_form`.`modified_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`sort_index`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`flagged_for_deletion` FROM `maqluengine_form` INNER JOIN `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue` ON (`maqluengine_form`.`id` = `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`form_parent_id`) WHERE (`maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id` = 319 AND `maqluengine_form`.`is_public` = True AND `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`record_value` LIKE %seal% AND `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`record_attribute_type_id` = 18510 AND `maqluengine_form`.`flagged_for_deletion` = False)
SELECT `maqluengine_form`.`id`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_name`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_number`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_geojson_string`, `maqluengine_form`.`hierarchy_parent_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`is_public`, `maqluengine_form`.`project_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_created`, `maqluengine_form`.`created_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_last_modified`, `maqluengine_form`.`modified_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`sort_index`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`flagged_for_deletion` FROM `maqluengine_form` INNER JOIN `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue` ON (`maqluengine_form`.`id` = `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`form_parent_id`) WHERE (`maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id` = 319 AND `maqluengine_form`.`is_public` = True AND `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`record_value` LIKE %seal% AND `maqluengine_formrecordattributevalue`.`record_attribute_type_id` = 18510)
```

The first takes about 20/30 seconds to perform the count(), while the second with only 1 of the two BooleanField's takes less than a second to perform the count()

=======================================
EDIT=======================
Apologies: since the question isn't obvious enough--why is adding an additional AND with a BooleanField increasing the query time by +2000%? Is anyone able to assist in figuring out WHY that's occurring.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?  Use MySQL `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan for the queries; very likely that the join order is different and/or different indexes are being used. One possible fix would be to alter the DJango so it produces SQL with condition **`HAVING`** `maqluengine_form.flagged_for_deletion = False` in place of **`AND`** (i.e. move that condition from the `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT=========================

Also discovered that using a exclude(is_public=False)  rather than filter(is_public=True) has the same effect as the solution below. Does anyone happen to know why an exclude() works fine--whereas the filter() does not?

==============================

Solution I came up with after a night's rest:

--I keep the query as is(I need it for later because it continues getting chain filtered)
--I need the count() from this stage--which is taking substantially longer than it should with the additional BooleanField AND
--I take a temporary values list to perform a len() on instead:

```
queriedForms = queryFormtype.form_set.all()
newQuery = queriedForms.filter(formrecordattributevalue__record_value__icontains=term['TVAL'], formrecordattributevalue__record_attribute_type__pk=rtypePK)
newQuery = newQuery.filter(flagged_for_deletion=False)
tempQuery = newQuery.values_list('is_public',flat=True)
finalQuery = [entry for entry in tempQuery if entry != 'False'] #Remove any indices that contain "False"
term['count'] =  len(finalQuery)
```

The following counts that use chained filters after use the same technique--it's significantly faster--if not as fast as removing one of the Booleans from the filters.